# Switching between channel accounts

Tags: youtube-api

I'd like to have a way to allow users to switch between channels that they are managing.

The app doesn't seem to recognize the new identity after I've gone to YouTube.com and switched to another channel backed by a G+ Page I'm managing. Let's call this Channel B. When I return to my app, it seems to always choose the main YouTube channel (linked to my @gmail.com account) as the default. Let's call this Channel A.

After signing out of YouTube and re-authenticating on my app as Channel B, I am able to operate as Channel B, but once I refresh the page, my identity gets switched back to Channel A.

Is there a good way to implement channel switching to ensure that my app always chooses the current YouTube channel account? I am using the gapi javascript libraries and would like to avoid writing server-side code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not manage channel switching or login activities. You only get one channel out of OAuth2.

Here is a little more detail: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase this into a channel identity persistence question.

Let's say the user has already authenticated into channel B, how do we persist that identity throughout the session? For the multi-page app, it looks like it will always automatically switch to channel A's identity when I navigate to the next page though I had already authenticated into channel B.

Comment: if I use the example of [link](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/DVj66wlZVZ1mT06ppzuLnZdF4aYJ5FW25xEpAybLxo1w7Dixpfm73ccFurm8YefQ5vnxps2k_ZsxEXjBSIGgenDwJBK1vWUnpMKCYszqvBQnsug1Rq2uxH31ww), even though I authenticate as channel "YouTube for Developers", when I navigate to the next page, the app thinks the current channel is "Jeffrey Posnick". Does that make sense?